# How long between the acceptance and proof correction of Elsevier?

Tags: publications, proofreading, elsevier

My paper has beed accepted by Elsevier's [International Journal of Electronics and Communications (AEUE)](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/aeu-international-journal-of-electronics-and-communications).

I want to know how long I should expect to wait until I receive the notice of online proof correction.

Comment: Note that "Elsevier" here is irrelevant: the publisher doesn't have anything to do with publication time frames. All that is up to the editors and referees.

Comment: Could you tell me how long did you get the first notification? This is because I also submitted one paper to AEU, but I have not gotten anything for 3 months.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can answer this question is to look at the date stamps sequences on some of the existing papers.  Many journals (including the one you have asked about), include all of the major dates in the publication process, e.g., "Received Date1, Accepted Date2, Available Online Date3," as well as the final date of publication.

Note that the "Available Online" and final date of publication may often be very different, but except in rare cases it is "Available Online" that you should care about because that is when people begin to be able to get your paper.  However, some journals do not do all of the final proof correction until closer to the date of publication, but essentially just have your preprint up online for quite some time!

Applying this analysis to this particular journal, one can find the following:

- Acceptance to available online looks like 1-3 weeks
- Final publication happens ~6 months later

So you will probably get contacted about the proof very quickly (if they follow the normal method of proofing before online availability), or not for several months (if they do late-binding proofing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I hope I can receive the notification in this month.

Answer (score 4):

The process between acceptance and receiving proofs contains a few steps. First the paper is likely to go to a copy-editor to check for inconsistencies in formatting and other issues dealing with the way the publisher wants the material presented in the final product. Following this is the type-setter who will set the paper, collate a set of questions, if any remain, for you to correct and then send out the proof for you to carefully proof read. The persons involved may have varying workloads, they usually are not working with one journal alone. In addition, the flow of papers is rarely constant in time so their workload can also vary in time for that reason.

As a result the time can vary substantially. I would say that a month is by no means unreasonable, it could be slightly shorter but can also be significantly longer. If the journal published on-line and provides acceptance dates on the published papers, you can estimate this by looking at the dates for acceptance and publishing on-line. This period also includes authors proof reading and final correction by the type-setter but that is usually about 2-3 weeks in total (can vary of course).